# How to play the video using opencv in android programatically?

Tags: android, opencv

As I'm fresher in android I did the image processing using OpenCV.Now I need to process the video that is I need to play the video using OpenCV.
Now I need to play the video in my app using OpenCV I tried using the videocapture class but it's getting an error that provides some implementation.So please help me in playing the video in my app using OpenCV.

Comment: take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401852/open-video-file-with-opencv-java

Comment: VideoCapture capture=new VideoCapture();//Here its expecting the argument
capture.open("Vid.mp4"); I had seen that code but actually even the video is not opening for me. and it is not playing the video.Please help me in playing the video

Answer (score 1):

Just giving the file name as an argument to the `capture.open()` wont work here, given that you are working on an android platform.

I took the below steps to resolve my problem, which is similar to yours.

1. Placed the video file under res/raw.
2. Copied the video file from res/raw to an [app specific directory](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific) ( I copied it to an external one, and I did this in a different thread from the UI/main thread )

   - Got the video file from res/raw as an *InputStream* via [`openRawResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#openRawResource(int))
   - Created an instance of [*File*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and created an instance of  *[FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File))* based on it.
   - Wrote the input stream to the output stream. You could use [`transferTo(OutputStream out)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo-java.io.OutputStream-), however it is only available in Java 9+. You can also follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8664527/11200630) as well.
3. Used the Absolute path of the recently copied file as the argument, via [`getAbsolutePath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()), in the *VideoCapture* Constructor or in [`open(String FileName)`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/videoio/VideoCapture.html#open(java.lang.String)).

Note: I understand this question was asked 3 years ago; I'm posting this as I think this might be useful for those who stumble upon this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried following the steps given by @Kalai. It seems to work. I did not face any errors. Giving the code in the hope it could help someone.

I kept my video file in the raw directory.

[image]

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
            Log.e("OpenCV", "Unable to load OpenCV!")
        else
            Log.d("OpenCV", "OpenCV loaded Successfully!")

        val absFilePath = moveFileFromRawToApp()
        openFileByOpenCV(absFilePath)
    }

private fun moveFileFromRawToApp(): String {
    val ins: InputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.marvel)
    val outFile = getAppSpecificDirectory("marvel.mp4")
    val out = FileOutputStream(outFile)
    val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    var buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    var size = ins.read(buffer, 0, 1024)
    while (size >= 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, size)
        size = ins.read(buffer, 0, 1024)
    }
    ins.close()
    buffer = outputStream.toByteArray()
    out.write(buffer)
    out.close()
    return outFile.absolutePath
}

private fun getAppSpecificDirectory(filename: String): File {
    val file = File(baseContext.filesDir, filename)
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile()
    }
    return file
}

private fun openFileByOpenCV(absFilePath: String) {
    val videoCapture = VideoCapture()
    videoCapture.open(absFilePath)
    Toast.makeText(this, "OpenCV worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

At the end you will have a video file in your mobile device **data > data > [package name] > files > marvel.mp4**

[image]